# Why is this binary tree code wrong?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I'm coding something I thought was simple for my programming class but I'm a little stuck :S, could someone take a look at my code, and help me? Thx

Der = right;

Izq = left;

```
    public boolean eliminaDatoABB(T dato){      
       if(this.isEmpty()||this.containsABBRecursivo(dato)==false)
           return false;
       return eliminaDatoABBUtil(this.raiz, dato);

     }

    private boolean deleteDatumABBUtil(NodeTree<T> nodo, T datum){
    if(nodo==null)
        return false;
    int i = nodo.nodeValue.compareTo(dato);
    if(i==0){ //Found it
        //Cases
        if(isLeaf(nodo)){ //Is leaf
            nodo=null;
            return true;
        }
        else
            if((hasChildRight(nodo)&&!hasChildLeft(nodo))){ //Has just one child at right
                NodoArbol<T> tmp = new NodoArbol<T>(nodo.der.nodeValue);
                tmp.der=nodo.der.der;
                tmp.izq=nodo.der.izq;
                nodo=tmp;
                //The trash collector should then delete the nodo.der
                return true;
            }
            else
                if((!hasChildRight(nodo)&&hasChildLeft(nodo))){ //Has just one child at left
                    NodoArbol<T> tmp = new NodoArbol<T>(nodo.izq.nodeValue);
                    tmp.izq=nodo.izq.izq;
                    tmp.der=nodo.izq.der;
                    nodo=tmp;
                    //The trash collector should then delete the nodo.izq
                    return true;
                }
                else{ //Has two children
                    NodoArbol<T> tmp = this.predecesor(nodo);
                    tmp.der=nodo.der;
                    tmp.izq=nodo.izq;
                    return deleteDatumABB(nodo.izq.nodeValue);
                }
    }
    else{ //Search the datum
        if(i>0)
            return deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.izq, dato);
        else
            return deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.der, dato);
    }
}

//Bonus Methods

public boolean isLeaf(NodeTree<T> nodo){
    return (nodo.der==null&&nodo.izq==null);
}

public boolean hasChildRight(NodeTree<T> nodo){
    return nodo.der!=null;
}

public boolean hasChildLeft(NodeTree<T> nodo){
    return nodo.izq!=null;
}
```

It doesn't work for any of the 3 cases :S

Comment: What is going wrong right now?

Comment: The node doesn't delete, it doesn't crash or anything but the datum just stays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this piece of code looks suspicious

```
nodo.der.der=nodo.der;
nodo.der.izq=nodo.izq;
```

Just look, here you assign children of `nodo` to `nodo`'s right child and then do the following

```
nodo = nodo.der
```

In fact you got that `nodo.der == nodo.der`, so I doubt that you really wanted to achieve such thing.

Just review those pieces of code and I'm sure you'll find where you're wrong.

Comment: You were right, I think I have corrected that piece of code, but the problem persists :S

Comment: Well, but `nodo`'s right(left) child could have more than 1 child itself even if `nodo` has only one:) Or it should be like that by design? BTW, why you don't call `deleteDatumABB` in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Some more suspicious places in code:

```
NodoArbol<T> tmp = this.predecesor(nodo);
tmp.der=nodo.der;
tmp.izq=nodo.izq;
return deleteDatumABB(nodo.izq.nodeValue);
```

First, if `this.predecesor(nodo)` really returns the predecesor of `nodo` then why are you rewriting its children?

Second, `deleteDatumABB(nodo.izq.nodeValue)` shouldn't it be `deleteDatumABB(tmp, datum)` or something like this?

And the question from my comment: is not calling `deleteDatumABB` in cases with only one child right?

Comment: it returns a new node that just has the predecesor nodeValue, and it has null values for der & izq attributes, so I'm just defining the der and izq attributes of the temporal node with the deleted node ones, then I delete the predecesor node (which now it's repeated).<br> Then I added a method that hasn't been copied at forst chance that just receives the datum.<br> To third question I have corrected that :)

Comment: Which really makes me think is that it doesn't work even for leaf nodes, I have debugged, and when I'm standing at the desired node, and want to delete it (null it) it succesfuly nulls it and returns true (all right so far), but when I print the tree the node magically reappears!

Comment: It is because `nodo` in fact is just an argument for your function. So, if you write `nodo = null` then you nullify only the argument reference. If you want to remove this node from the tree you need to nullify reference in its parent node.

Comment: Yes, and I think the real problem is that you are wrongly think about the reference as about the real object. When you call a method you are not passing the object itself, but you passing the reference to it. Its like a pointer to something in C. You can make the pointer to point to another object but the object itself will not dissapear. And other objects will still refer to it.

Comment: Oh damn I think I just didn't get exactly how java works, so basically I got 2 fundamental situations, when I want to delete the root node, and when I can kill a node through it's parent... right?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. In other words, to "kill" a node you need just to remove all references to it. In trees the only reference to the node usually is the reference from its parent. So if `node` is a right child of `parent` then it sufficient to set `parent.right = null`. But if you write `node = null` there is still would be `parent.right != null`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Xappymah, I have corrected my code succesfully and now it works like a charm, to anyone that would like to se the code, here it is :D :

```
public boolean deleteDatumABB(T datum){
if(this.isEmpty())
    return false;
return deleteDatumABBUtil(this.root, datum);

}
private boolean deleteDatumABBUtil(NodeTree<T> nodo, T datum){
    if(nodo==null)
        return false;
    int i = nodo.nodeValue.compareTo(dato);
    if(i==0){ //Found it :D
        //Base cases
        if(isLeaf(nodo)){ //Is Leaf
            if(this.root==nodo){
                this.root=null;
                return true;
            }
            else{
                NodeTree<T> parent = getParentABBRecursivePriv(root, datum);
                if(dato.compareTo(parent.nodeValue)<0)
                    parent.izq=null;
                else
                    parent.der=null;    
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            if((hasChildRight(nodo)&&!hasChildLeft(nodo))){ //Just one kind at right
                if(nodo==this.root){
                    this.root=nodo.der;
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    NodeTree<T> parent = getParentABBRecursivoPriv(root, dato);
                    if(datum.compareTo(prent.nodeValue)<0)
                        parent.izq = nodo.der;
                    else
                        parent.der = nodo.der;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
                if((!hasChildRight(nodo)&&hasChildLeft(nodo))){ //TJust one child at left
                    if(nodo==this.root){
                        this.root=nodo.izq;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        NodeTree<T> parent = getParentABBRecursivePriv(root, datum);
                        if(datum.compareTo(parent.nodeValue)<0)
                            parent.izq = nodo.izq;
                        else
                            parent.der = nodo.izq;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else{ //Children in both
                    if(nodo==this.raiz){

                        NodoArbol<T> pred = new NodeTree<T>(predecesor(nodo).nodeValue);
                        pred.der = this.root.der;
                        pred.izq = this.root.izq;

                        this.root = pred;
                        deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.izq, root.nodeValue);



                        return true;
                    }
                    else{

                        NodeTree<T> parent = getParentABBRecursivePriv(root, datum);
                        NodoArbol<T> pred = new NodeTress<T>(predecesor(nodo).nodeValue);
                        pred.der = padre.der.der;
                        pred.izq = padre.der.izq;
                        deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.izq, pred.nodeValue);
                        parent.der = pred;
                        return true;
                    }

                }
    }
    else{ //Search
        if(i>0)
            return deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.izq, datum);
        else
            return deleteDatumABBUtil(nodo.der, datum);
    }
}
```